# current_user and destroying comments (refined)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, destroy

I recently posted a question similar to this but I've narrowed down the problem and wanted to refine the question. Anyway, I have a blog with recipes (equivalent of posts or articles) and comments on those recipes. I've put in my application_controller.rb file the code for current_user:

```
def current_user
  return unless session[:user_id]
  @current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
end

# Make current_user available in templates as a helper
helper_method :current_user
```

I tried to make it so that you had to be logged in to delete a comment on an article. That code is in my comments_controller.rb file:

```
def destroy
  @recipe = current_user.recipes.find(params[:recipe_id])
  @comment = @recipe.comments.find(params[:id])
  @comment.destroy
  redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Comment Deleted'
end
```

I've narrowed it down to that first line of code within the destroy method. I believe that my application can't associate the recipe with the current_user and so can't save @recipe properly, so the @comment won't delete. Each recipe has a user_id parameterHere's the error, from the server console, when I try to delete a comment with a logged in user:

```
Started DELETE "/recipes/4/comments/4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-12 13:42:54 -0500

Processing by CommentsController#destroy as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"+0pWfNOPJXLOzgUhA//q4ySh5rk01SlKmTRQx0qdDOrvkUOcIzF8GCb5jKwjsDlUvQsxxGTOOtJv6rPjn3jfoA==", "recipe_id"=>"4", "id"=>"4"}

User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 6]]

Recipe Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE "recipes"."user_id" = ? AND "recipes"."id" = ?  ORDER BY published_at DESC, title ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 6], ["id", 4]]

Completed 404 Not Found in 50ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Recipe with 'id'=4 [WHERE "recipes"."user_id" = ?]):
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:15:in `destroy'
```

Anyone have any ideas?

NOTE: when I change the first line of code within the destroy method of my comments_controller to:

```
@recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
```

it works. I don't want that to be the code though bc then a non-logged in user can delete comments. AND, that revised code is the same code as a private method i put within my comments_controller:

```
private
def load_recipe
  @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
end
```

There is also a before_filter on that method in my comments_controller:

```
before_filter :load_recipe, :except => :destroy
before_filter :authenticate, :only => :destroy
```

Comment: Make sure Recipe with id = 4 has user_id set to 6

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'm still new to programming; that must have been a very blatant mistake on my part. I appreciate the help though